# Changing multiple lines in to single line with spaces in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have following data with multiple lines

```
username: joe
empid: 1111
status: resigned

username: tom
emid: 1234

username: kate
empid: 2222
status: resigned
```

What I want is to get the data in to other file as below

```
username: joe,empid: 1111,status: resigned
username: tom,empid: 1234
username: kate,empid: 2222,status: resigned
```

Best Wishes,
KJ

Comment: Do you know how to use any of the editors?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter perl version:

```
perl -000 -ne 's/\n+/,/g; s/,$//g; print "$_\n"' filename.txt
```

The `-000` activates paragraph mode where multiple successive newlines define an input record.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/,/' filename.txt | perl -p -e 's/,,/\n/g' | perl -p -e 's/,\Z/\n/g'
```

The first command replaces newlines with commas, the second puts the newline back where there where two newlines before and the third one removes the last comma artifact and replaces it with a newline.

It is probably possible to do all of this in one command, but I am not familiar enough with `perl` to do it. The reason I use it here is that `sed` does not offer an easy solution to replace newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk,

```
gawk '{s=$1 $2;for(i=3;i<NF;i+=2) {s=s "," $i $(i+1)}print s}' RS= IFS=":"  input.txt
```

But note that this "eats" spaces after the "field separator" (:).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `tr`:

```
tr '\n' ',' filename.txt
```

Comment: This won't work, it will print everything in a single line. Also, `tr` needs the file to be redirected, `tr 'a' 'b' < file.txt`.